# Parsing a huge text file gives me a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to parse a relatively big text file in C. I cannot use `malloc` or `realloc`. Words should be tokenized based on `"/"` as you can see. However the code below gives me a segmentation error even if `i` change the size of the array.

```
char buf[1000];
char *token;
char tags[500][1000];
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

for (i = 0; fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);) {

            token = strtok(buf, " /");
            while (token != NULL) {
                strcpy(tags[i], token);
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL, " /");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The value if `i` is what, the moment the program crashes?

Comment: Need check `i < 500`.

Comment: The does not just tokenise on `'/'` but also on `' '`, BTW.

Comment: This is the real code and its working for the first 3-4 sentences. I want this to be tokenized on space so i think is good.

Comment: @LucasSmith: My eyes got confused, by to many nested parenthesis.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Well, it's not good because it fails and because you don't bounds-check on 'i', as @BLUEPIXY already pointed out.  Why do you not printf out 'i' as a check,(debugging 101)?

Comment: @n.m.: Probably not, if tokenisation is "*working for the first 3-4 sentences*".

Comment: @MartinJames: "*debugging 101*"? I am no native speaker.

Comment: @alk https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(number)#In_education

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 500 && fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);) { }
```

Otherwise we can get array out of bounds error and a crash would occur. 
This is C after all.

Comment: I am sorry about the typo, I meant " i <500 "